# Running apache, php and mysql on blackberry

Tags: php, mysql, apache, blackberry, localhost

Can i run apache server, php engine and mysql database on a blackberry device (device, not simulator)?

When i search at google, the results are how to do it on blackberry **simulator**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about a BB 7 or earlier phones, the ones that run Java, the answer is a flat no.  Never.

For BB10 devices (like Z10 or Q10), I am not so sure.  These devices run a version of the QNX OS, and I have seen articles that talk about running Apache etc on QNX. I would review these articles to see if they provide any answers.